# ThreeTenABP: How to validate date using a custom date format / DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, android, threetenbp

I'm using [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) and seem to have run into a difference of implementation between LocalDate.parse(String) and LocalDate.parse(String, DateTimeFormatter).

```
LocalDate.parse("31/02/1985", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Parses to "1985-02-28" without throwing an exception.

```
LocalDate.parse("2015-02-31")
```

DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-02-31' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31'

The [documentation](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) *almost* implies this with "The string must represent a valid date" only mentioned with the formatter-less method.

How can I validate a date in a custom format like 31/02/1985 using threeten bp?

Comment: For others going down this same rabbit hole as I - see this for custom formats containing years and strict resolving - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393594/using-new-java-8-datetimeformatter-to-do-strict-date-parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference can be explained by the fact that the ISO_LOCAL_DATE-formatter is strict by default. Other formatters are [smart](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/ResolverStyle.html) by default. The full sentence you cited reads like this:

> The string must represent a valid date and is parsed using
>   DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.

So it is pretty clear that the formatter-less method can only parse ISO-compatible dates in strict mode, and even then only a [subset of ISO-8601](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE), namely:

`uuuu-MM-dd` or `uuuuMMdd`

About the strict mode, you can see it studying the [source code](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.java):

```
   public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_DATE; 
   static { 
     ISO_LOCAL_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder() 
       .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD) 
       .appendLiteral('-') 
       .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2) 
       .appendLiteral('-') 
       .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2) 
       .toFormatter(ResolverStyle.STRICT).withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE); 
     }
```

However, the strict mode does not seem to be well documented. Anyway, if you want to realize the strict mode with a custom formatter then simply call its method [withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withResolverStyle-org.threeten.bp.format.ResolverStyle-).

Comment: Yay!   `DateTimeParseException: Text '31/02/1985' could not be parsed`.  Of course now it can't actually parse valid dates, but that's another problem.  Thank you. :)