# DateTimeFormatter - ResolverStyle issue

Tags: java, datetimeformatter

I'm wanting to create a `LocalDate` instance by parsing a String with a DateTimeFormatter, I noticed that if I parse a string where the day is greater than the number of days in the month then the smart resolver just resolves it to the last day for example. (I want the exception to be thrown)

```
    DateTimeFormatter smartFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    
    LocalDate.parse("20000431", smartFormatter);
```

This is resolved to 30th April 2000, so I added the following

```
    DateTimeFormatter strictFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    
    LocalDate.parse("20000431", strictFormatter);
```

As expected this now throws an exception. However, I've noticed that it also throws an exception for the 30th April, which is obviously valid. What's wrong with the below?

```
    DateTimeFormatter strictFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    
    LocalDate.parse("20000430", strictFormatter);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393594/using-new-java-8-datetimeformatter-to-do-strict-date-parsing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103603/issue-with-datetimeparseexception-when-using-strict-resolver-style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `yyyy` means *year-of-era*. `STRICT`ly speaking, such date probably expects "AD" or "BC" to be present.

If you change the pattern string to

```java
uuuuMMdd
```

it'll work.

Despite the fact that `yyyy` *looks* like a natural way to express "the current year", it does not actually *mean* "the current year", but rather "the current year in the current era".

You should always use `uuuu` instead of `yyyy`.