# How to make LocalDateTime.parse reject 24:00 time

Tags: kotlin, java-time, datetimeformatter

I have a form where user can input date and time from keypad and LocalDateTime accepts input when time part of input is 24:00, converting it to next day.

My code

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val INPUT_DATETIME_PATTERN = "yyyyMMddHHmm"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(INPUT_DATETIME_PATTERN)
    
val datetime = "202308102400"

val localdatetime = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, formatter)
println(datetime)
println(localdatetime.format(formatter))
```

Expected result:
LocalDateTime.parse throws an exception.
According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), HH stands for hour-of-day (0-23), so 2400 is invalid. Exception is also thrown for input string 202308102401.

Actual result:
202308110000 is printed. Checked in a scratch in Android Studio and in Kotlin playground ([link](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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))

Comment: Could this help somehow? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedExcessDays--

Comment: Gosh, I had the feeling this is one of those issues that can be resolved by reading the docs *really* carefully. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it is my fault for not reading documentation with enough attention... Thanks Marco F. for pointing me at what I missed.

`DateTimeResolver` is created with `ResolverStyle.SMART` by default which performs [sensible default for each field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART), e.g. interpreting 24:00 as "first moment of next day" or allows month-of-day values up to 31, silently converting to actual valid day values.

Correct code to get the expected behavior:

```
val INPUT_DATETIME_PATTERN = "uuuuMMddHHmm"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern(INPUT_DATETIME_PATTERN)
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)

val datetime = "202308102400"

val localdatetime = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, formatter)
println(datetime)
println(localdatetime.format(formatter))
```

Note also that year specifier is changed from yyyy (year of era) to uuuu (year), because strict resolver requires an era to go with YearOfEra ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41104034/7119522)).

Answer (score 3):

(In Java syntax, not Kotlin)

### tl;dr

To reject such inputs, specify a strict resolver style.

```
DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" )
    .withResolverStyle( ResolverStyle.STRICT )
```

> LocalDateTime accepts input when time part of input is 24:00, converting it to next day

Yes, it should do that. What you see is a **feature, not a bug**.

Using 24:00 on a 00-23 clock means “end of today” which is also “beginning of tomorrow”. So logically:

```
( 202308102400 = 202308110000 ) -> true
```

This specific behavior [is documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedExcessDays--).

### 24:00 *does* mean the next day

[`24:00` means](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) the first moment of the *next* day. In contrast, 00:00 means the first moment of the specified day.

Conceptually, every day has *two* midnights, one at the beginning of the day, and one at the end of the day. To avoid this ambiguity, notice that the *java.time* classes avoid both the term and the concept of “midnight”. Instead the *java.time* classes focus on the [first moment of the day](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay(java.time.ZoneId)).

Some industries differentiate between the two midnights by using `00:00` & `24:00`. They use the `24:00` notation as a way of saying “at the end of the day today”.

So we see that `202308102400` is the same as `202308110000`. The end of the day today is also the beginning of the day tomorrow.

So the behavior of `LocalDateTime` is semantically correct, returning to you the date of the next day along with the time-of-day of 00:00.

See the following code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Lc4OXv)

```
    final DateTimeFormatter BASIC_ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" ) ;
    String input = "202308102400" ; 
    try {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( input , BASIC_ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ) ;
        System.out.println( "ldt.toString() = " + ldt ) ;
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        System.out.println( "Yuck. Your input is distasteful. " ) ;
    }
```

> ldt.toString() = 2023-08-11T00:00

### Check input with `String#endsWith`

If in your case you are certain the time `24:00` should be rejected, you could simply check tho string input for the presence of `2400` [at the end](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)).

```
if ( input.endsWith( "2400" ) { … }
else { LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ; }
```

### `Resolver.STRICT`

As [you eventually found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76998745/642706), to make the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withResolverStyle-java.time.format.ResolverStyle-) object reject inputs with a time of 24:00, set the [`ResolverStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html) to the enum object [`STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT). Strict mode will tolerate only hours of 00-23.

```
    final DateTimeFormatter STRICT_BASIC_ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME = 
        DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" )
            .withResolverStyle( ResolverStyle.STRICT ) ;  // <— Reject 2400 as time of day.
```

Catch [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) to handle such unwelcome inputs.

```
    String input = "202308102400" ; 
    try {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( input , STRICT_BASIC_ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ) ;
        System.out.println( "ldt.toString() = " + ldt ) ;
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        System.out.println( "Yuck. Your input is distasteful. " ) ;
    }
```

Comment: Yep, I figured it is likely a feature I don't want in my case and wanted a way to turn it off. It was that DateTimeFormater was created with ResolverStyle.SMART by default, while I needed ResolverStyle.STRICT.

Comment: A well-researched answer! All tye links in the answer are valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Change your line 
`val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(INPUT_DATETIME_PATTERN)`

to
`val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(INPUT_DATETIME_PATTERN).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)`
See this question for more info: [Using new Java 8 DateTimeFormatter to do strict date parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393594/using-new-java-8-datetimeformatter-to-do-strict-date-parsing)
Also, in your format change year part from '`yyyy`' to '`uuuu`'. It won't work without this.

Comment: @OleV.V. you are correct, once I switched 'yyyy' part to 'uuuu' it worked. Updating the answer

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val INPUT_DATETIME_PATTERN = "yyyyMMddHHmm"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(INPUT_DATETIME_PATTERN)

val datetime = "202308102400"
val adjustedDatetime = datetime.replaceRange(8..9, "00")

val localdatetime = LocalDateTime.parse(adjustedDatetime, formatter)
println(datetime)
println(localdatetime.format(formatter))
```

This code adjusts the time part from "2400" to "0000" before parsing the datetime string and produces the expected output

Comment: I did it by checking if symbols 8-9 are equal to 24 to get my expected behavior, but still, it's an additional check that seems like it's supposed to be done internally by parse().

Comment: Especially when LocalDateTime.of() which accepts same ranges as my formatter rejects time 24:00:00.

Comment: can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I figured out a solution and posted it as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76998745/7119522